# Does service launched from its activity runs in a new Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-intent, android-asynctask

Launching a service for first time from its activity like

```
this.startService(new Intent(this,UpdaterService.class));
```

does this service runs in a new thread ? 
And if I put heavy work load on this service (without taking help of thread) will android will show force close for this application ??

And how different is AsyncTask class from Thread class ?? 
which one to use where ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android developer manual reads](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

- A `Service` is not a separate process.
  The `Service` object itself does not
  imply it is running in its own
  process; unless otherwise specified,
  it runs in the same process as the
  application it is part of.
- A `Service` is not a thread. It is not
  a means itself to do work off of the
  main thread (to avoid `Application` Not
  Responding errors).

Comment: @jason _A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user_ - **RTFM**

Answer (score 1):

Service is running in a different process, it's just an application without a user interface. AsyncTask is just a helper class that helps you do some work on a separate thread and synchronize it with your UI thread, for example to show current progress to your users. You can use AsyncTask when you need this type of synchronization, but generally there is no big difference between using any of these. Hope this helps.